# Changing background-size requires new background-position, any workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 1320x1320 spritesheet, each individual image is 120x120, 121 total images. I have been using this formula to set the background-position up until now:

`image[i].style.backgroundPosition = -120*i + "px " + -Math.floor(i/11)*120 + "px"`

Now that I'm close to finishing my project, I wanted to update some of the quick fixes I made, so that I don't use 121 Math.floor's to load all the images, and so it's easier to update them in the future without having to rearrange all the images in the spritesheet to be in alphabetical order when I add new ones. So I went and used a program to generate the current css positions for all my images, for example:

`.image[1]{-600px -480px;}
.image[2]{-1200px -840px;}
.image[3]{-1200px -720px;}
.image[4]{-1200px -600px;}`

but the problem with this is, if I change the background-size, it completely ruins the position for all the images. There's an instance where I load all the images at once, so the user can select one of them, but to show 121 images at once I need to downsize it a little, so I go from 120x120 to 72x72 with background-size, but the positioning gets ruined with the new method, does anyone have a work around to this?

All the background-size + background-position issue threads I've seen have been about percentages and something entirely different than what I'm having.

Comment: I would suggest using a CSS processor like Stylus, SASS, or LESS, you can write loops to calculate the positions

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want to shrink the elements you could always use a css3

```
  transform: scale(.5)
```

and its webkit/firefox counterparts.

For your first point about the Math.floor() I really don't see an issue. Just put the initialization in a loop and you should be fine.

If you really want use a i%11 instead of the floor.

Hope that anwsers your question.